# Mathematical formulation for detrmining a smallest value from a set

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling to find a nice formal mathematical way to express the following statement:

$L_{a} = \min (|ab_a - ab_{a'}|, |ab_a - ae_{a'}|)): \forall a'\in A, X_{a'}=1$

In other words, I wanted to say that for all elements $a'$ from the set A such that $X_{a'}=1$, determine the smallest difference between some value of element $a$ and $a'$.
That is, I would like to represent a loop through a number of elements to find a  minimal difference of their values.

I would be very gratefull for any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: The minimum value as $a$ ranges through what? The minimum over all $a$ in a particular set?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eric. I tried to simplify the question as much as possible. Given a set of elements A, which all have two associated values named 'ab' and 'ae', I would like to find the smallest difference between the values of an element a from A and all the other elements from A, a' \in A for which Xa'=1

Comment: Some context might help for this. What are ab and ae? There might be some better notation for those. As it is, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Question: would it be alright if $ab_a$ were replaced with $f(a)$ and $ae_a$ with $g(a)$? Because two-letter variable names are *very* non-standard in math, and tend to be confused with multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. ab_a and ae_a represent the begin and end time of activity a \in A. I will replace this notation by b(a) and e(a).

Answer (score 2):

If $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, say, we could write

$$d(A,B):= \min \{|b-a| : a\in A, b \in B\}$$

or for the distance from a single number $c$ we might write

$$\min_{a\in A}|c-a|$$